# Setup different frontend & backend application endpoints in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've posted this on Laravel.io too, but no answer yet: http://laravel.io/forum/01-17-2016-setup-different-frontend-backend-application-endpoints

I've been struggling figuring this out but no luck yet - couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I have a regular public-facing website for which I need an admin interface. Assuming the website is at example.com, I want the admin interface to be accessible from example.com:3000.

I've tried domain routing, it doesn't seem to be working. The idea is to share all the business logic, but isolate assets and routes - for instance, accessing "/" would produce different results on the frontend (showing the homepage) and on the backend (showing a dashboard). I also need different middleware authentication, but I have a hunch that's going to be easy once I figure out how to set this up.

If it's easy to add different sessions, that would also be cool, but I can live without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on laracasts: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/setup-different-frontend-backend-endpoints-in-laravel-51 , I'll quote from the answer here:

> You can pull it off by editing the app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider
>   and loading in a specific routes file based on the "context" of the
>   application.
>
> You could create two routes files /app/Http/Routes/frontend.php and
>   /app/Http/Routes/backend.php. You'll do some sort of logic in the
>   RouteServiceProvider to determine what route file to load in.